# Quadratic curve classification- case of a circle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

This [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticCurve.html) gives a table providing classification of conics in terms of $\Delta, I$ and $J$.
If $\Delta\ne 0,J>0,\frac{\Delta}{I}<0$, then the curve is a real ellipse.

I want to know about the classification where this ellipse is a circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values $Δ,I,J,K$ don't allow us to characterize a circle. Circles are precisely those ellipses where the value $a = c$. None of the quantities describe this nicely.

Answer (score 1):

A circle is just a special case of an ellipse where the lengths of the semi-major and semi-minor axes are the same. Thus, the classification for circles is the same as that for ellipses. At the most, a circle might limit the ranges of these values (i.e., $\Delta, I$ and $J$) within those regions (i.e., non-zero, positive or negative) compared to what an ellipse may have.

Note the page you linked to even explicitly says this

> ... (the ellipse and its special case the circle, ...

Comment: I know the circle is a special case of an ellipse however I am wondering can we classify the circle case in terms of $\Delta,I,J,K$?

Comment: @mathisgood The point is that the specific minimal classifications for a real ellipse, i.e., as you stated $\Delta\ne 0,J>0,\frac{\Delta}{I}<0$, are the *same* as those for a circle since they just specify only about being non-zero, positive or negative, so a circle would not have anything more specific being required among these very general comparisons. At the most, a circle might limit the ranges of these values within those regions (i.e., non-zero, positive or negative) compared to what an ellipse may have.

Comment: Yes, you are right.